# Sampling a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\left\{ x_i \right\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence such that $x_{i+1} > x_i$ I'm trying to prove or disprove or find conditions under which the sequence $\left\{ f(x_i) \right\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$.

I believe it might be, but I'm not sure. I've tried to tackle it by taking the specific case $f : \mathbb{R} \to [0,+\infty]$ then I know there's a sequence of simple functions $s_n \to f$ such that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} s_n(x) dx \to \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx 
$$

So if instead of $f$ I use $|f|^2$ I know there's a sequence of simple functions such that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} s_n(x) dx \to \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx
$$

I can pick $s_n$ as

$$
s_n(x) = \sum_{j-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x_j)|^2\chi_{A_j}(x)\mu(A_j)
$$

where the family $\left\{A_j\right\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a family of disjoint measurable sets. So I can specifically pick these $A_j$ all to have measure $1$ and hence

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} s_n dx = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} \left|f(x_j)\right|^2
$$

which is bounded.
It's more of a hunch rather than a formal argument, but I'd like to know if I'm on the right track.

I guess every simple function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ has the property I'm trying to prove my question is whether this holds in general.

Comment: Question: as $L^2$ is a space of functions that can be redefined on sets of zero-measure - how do you define a sample?

Comment: Pick $f = \chi_{\mathbb{N}}$ and $g = 0$. Pick $x_n = n$. Note the sample of $f$ is not in $l^2$, but the sample of $g$ is. However, $f=g$ in $L^2$. So?

Comment: Evaluation is not well-defined in $L^2$, that's the issue.

Comment: Can I make leverage on some dense subspace of continuous functions? Like $C_0(\mathbb{R})$? (as defined in Rudin - Real and Complex analysis).

Comment: I meant $C_c(X)$, i.e. set of continuous functions whose supports is compact in $X$.

Comment: What if you define a sample as a linear continuos operator on a suitable dense subspace, and extend it by Hahn-Banach?

Comment: I guess this is well defined in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ and this could then be extended on the whole $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?. If $T_{x_0} : C_c(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $T_{x_0}(f) = f(x_0)$ but I don't think this is bounded (in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ norm).

Comment: It is unbounded in the quadratic norm, yes.

Comment: To be fair however Hahn-Banach does not require the functional to be bounded https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem (according to the statement at least).

Comment: It does require it in the "good cases", tho. Could you give me some ideas about the reason you're defining such a sample?

Comment: Just as an exercise really, and I also wonder if it is possible to construct $l^2$ sequences from $L^2$ functions. I might have had a thought. I think I can define the sample in terms of essential supremum. It's probably for another question however, I'll create it in a bit.

Comment: $\ell^2$ sequences can be related to $L^2$ functions via Fourier coefficients.

Comment: I agree but you need somehow to restrict your functions to a bounded interval, which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Pass me the new question's link once it is ready.

Comment: @FranCruz Done, link : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004930/sampling-a-measurable-function